# Policy Iteration Diagram in Jack’s Car Rental (in reinforcement learning)

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Can anyone help explain a bit more on the diagrams in the Jack’s Car Rental example of Richard Sutton's book "Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction"? The image is like this: [image]

I don't understand what is the meaning of all the stepwise curves and 1-2-3-4 stands for per each policy $\pi_{i}$

The detailed description of the case is as below: (quoted)

> Example 4.2: Jack’s Car Rental Jack manages two locations for a
>   nationwide car rental company. Each day, some number of customers
>   arrive at each location to rent cars. If Jack has a car available, he
>   rents it out and is credited \$10 by the national company. If he is
>   out of cars at that location, then the business is lost.
>
> Cars become available for renting the day after they are returned. To
>   help ensure that cars are available where they are needed, Jack can
>   move them between the two locations overnight, at a cost of \$2 per
>   car moved. We assume that the number of cars requested and returned at
>   each location are Poisson random variables, meaning that the
>   probability that the number is n is $ \frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}
> > e^{-\lambda} $, where λ is the expected number.  Suppose λ is 3 and 4
>   for rental requests at the first and second locations and 3 and 2 for
>   returns.
>
> To simplify the problem slightly, we assume that there can be no more
>   than 20 cars at each location (any additional cars are returned to the
>   nationwide company, and thus disappear from the problem) and a maximum
>   of five cars can be moved from one location to the other in one night.
>   We take the discount rate to be γ = 0.9 and formulate this as a
>   continuing finite MDP, where the time steps are days, the state is the
>   number of cars at each location at the end of the day, and the actions
>   are the net numbers of cars moved between the two locations overnight.
>   Figure 4.2 shows the sequence of policies found by policy iteration
>   starting from the policy that never moves any cars.

Comment: A detailed explaination with an explicit construction of the transition matrix (as jupyter notebook for python/numpy) can be found here: https://www.deep-teaching.org/notebooks/reinforcement-learning/markov-decision-processes-and-optimal-control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stepped curves are showing the contours of the different policy actions, as a map over the state space. They are a choice of visualisation of the policy, which has 441 states, and would not look quite so intuitive listed as a table.

The numbers are the number of cars that the policy decides to move from first location to second location.

You can look up the optimal action from the $\pi_4$ graph for a specific number of cars at each location by finding the grid point $(n_{2}, n_{1})$ for it (reading horizontal axis first) and seeing what the number is inside that area - move that number of cars from first to second location.

The final image shows the state value function of the optimal policy as a 3D surface with the base being the state and the height being the value.

---

When I did this exercise, I could not find how to get the labeled contours using `matplotlib`, so I made a colour map instead:

[image]

Hotter colour increments mean move cars from first location to second location, the map orientation is different to the book.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation!! Have to say it takes me sometime to digest. Following the book with some python code also helps a lot.